# Variable Importance for different methods

Tags: modeling, importance

Is it possible to compare variable importance, obtained for different models, built on different datasets with simular variables, using caret package? The property are different, but close, and the variables used for modelling are the same. For example, one can calculate importance for pls and random forest model, then scale them to obtain values from 0 to 1. 
Would it be valid to compare such values for two different Y? Is there any way to compare two different statistical models, built on two different datasets in terms of variable influence?

Comment: When you say "different datasets" do you mean the same dataset( ex: wine dataset) which has been partitioned into different dataset or are trying to compare variable importance in the wine dataset with variable importance with Iris dataset? please clarify. As it stands your question does not make sense.

Comment: When I say different datasets, I mean datasets like let's say some imaginary beer and whisky datasets. The property would be different, but close, and the variables used for modelling are the same (let's say, % of alcohol and average density). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following additional information, I would suggest looking at avg. rank of a variable across datasets.

For ex:
Lets say we have a binary target variable, Like_or_not_like which is :

- 1 if the user liked the drink and
- 0 if the user didn't like the drink

Now, we have captured the following variables for a set of wines, beer & whiskies in three datasets respectively and would like to understand how variable importance changes by the type of drink:

- pH_level
- Sugar_Content
- Alcohol_Percentage
- Average_Density

You can get relative ranking for each variable in each dataset as output by each algorithm applied.

[image]

Then, you can simply avg. out the ranks to get a finally tally like the following:
[image]

NOTE: Lower the rank number, higher the importance.

Comment: One little additional question: can be ranking for PLS and RF (for example) compared?

Comment: I thought that's what I explained in my answer. You are only looking at relative ranking output by whatever method ( RF, PLS etc...) for each variable in question. You should study the 1st image in my answer.